# Why does not work ng-controller in HTML from AJAX?

Tags: angularjs

I have HTML code that is returned from AJAX:

```
<div ng-controller="CounterPostsController">
   <span ng-click="Do();"></span>
</div>
```

So, event `ng-click` does not work

Comment: could you please more code..and explain us what you want to achieve.

Comment: You need to show the surrounding code, maybe make a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Caur do you mean to say that you are making ajax using `Do()` call and you want to bind html to somewhere? please brief us..what you want?

Comment: No I do AJAX(Jquery) request that returns HTML code that I posted in question

Comment: @Caur Please write the definition of your controller(i.e. CounterPostsController) in the question. The question you have posted doesn't give any information to conclude anything.

Answer (score 0):

In your CounterPostsController, do you have the Do() method defined and associated to the $scope variable?

i.e. $scope.Do() = function () {}   or $scope.Do() = myCustomFunction;

You will need to associate your function to $scope in order the code above to work.

Hope this helps

Comment: I have all that about you have told